# SQL Server dynamic table variables and returning field variables from these tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am struggling to make this logic work in my stored procedure. My logic is simple. I have two stored procedures called in another stored procedure (see code below).

The idea is to return a date variable or the count of the records based on the input provided and populate values in the main stored procedure variables

The procedures run fine but I come across the following problems:

- `dbo.GetLastDate` doesn't return a date value
- `dbo.usr_GetRecCount` always returns 0, even when there are records in the table

Main stored procedure:

```
    ....
                Exec dbo.usr_GetLastDate @TableName, @LastTransDate
                EXEC dbo.usr_GetRecCount @TableName, @RecCount
    ...
```

`dbo.usr_GetLastDate`:

```
   ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usr_GetLastDate]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @TableName SYSNAME,
    @OUTDATE date Output
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

   DECLARE @SQLCommand NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
        N'SELECT @OUTDATE=MAX(TRANSDATE) FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName);

  EXECUTE [dbo].[sp_executesql] 
             @sqlCommand, N'@OUTDATE DATE OUTPUT', @OUTDATE=@OUTDATE OUTPUT;

END

`dbo.usr_GetRecCount`:

   ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usr_GetRecCount]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @ViewName SYSNAME,
    @OUTINT int output
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

   DECLARE @SQLCommand NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
        N'SELECT @OUTINT=COUNT(SYMBOL) FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@ViewName);


   EXECUTE [dbo].[sp_executesql] 
             @sqlCommand, N'@OUTINT INT OUTPUT', @OUTINT=@OUTINT OUTPUT;
END
```

Comment: Maye you should add a **space** after the `FROM` in your SQL statements - otherwise your statement will be `SELECT COUNT(Symbol) FROMMytable` and that might just not work ....

Comment: I fixed that still doesn't work. Also added the output parameter in the SP

Comment: What does "not work" mean?  This might be how you are calling them.  The parameter has to be declared `OUTPUT` when the stored procedure is executed.

Answer (score 3):

Use `sp_executesql` with an explicit `OUTPUT` parameter:

```
DECLARE @SQLCommand NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
            N'SELECT @OUTDATE = MAX(TRANSDATE) FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName);

DECLARE @OUTDATE DATE;

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand,
        N'@OUTDATE DATE OUTPUT',
        @OUTDATE=@OUTDATE OUTPUT;
```

A similar structure should be used for the second query as well.

Comment: Gordon: I tried this, but it did not work and still returned blank value for my date (@LastTransDate) and 0 for the record count (@RecCount)

Comment: Specify the `OUTPUT` keyword in the parameter declaration and parameter value assignment: `N'@OUTDATE DATE OUTPUT', @OUTDATE=@OUTDATE OUTPUT`

Comment: I did make those changes but still nothing. here is the code below

Comment: I made all the recommended changes but still having issues. Must be missing something critical, I;ll keep looking ... made some changes to the code .... anything wrong that  u guys see?

Comment: Adding an output flag at the end when calling the SP did the trick

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare and pass this variable as OUTPUT to get a value from the sql statement.

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX), @Value DATE;

 SET @SQL =  N'SELECT @Value = MAX(TRANSDATE) FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName);

EXECUTE [dbo].[sp_executesql] @SQL
                             ,N'@Value Date OUTPUT'
                             ,@Value OUTPUT

SELECT @Value AS RtnValue
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help. After adding corrections suggested by some of you this the final code that worked

```
** Main Procedure **
Exec dbo.usr_GetLastDate @TableName, @LastTransDate OUTPUT
EXEC dbo.usr_GetRecCount @TableName, @RecCount OUTPUT

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usr_GetLastDate]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @TableName SYSNAME,
    @OUTDATE date Output
    --<@Param2, sysname, @p2> <Datatype_For_Param2, , int> = <Default_Value_For_Param2, , 0>
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
   DECLARE @SQLCommand NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
        N'SELECT @OUTDATE=MAX(TRANSDATE) FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName);

   EXECUTE [dbo].[sp_executesql] 
             @sqlCommand, N'@OUTDATE DATE OUTPUT', @OUTDATE=@OUTDATE OUTPUT;

END

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usr_GetRecCount]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @TableName SYSNAME,
    @OUTINT int output
    --<@Param2, sysname, @p2> <Datatype_For_Param2, , int> = <Default_Value_For_Param2, , 0>
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
   DECLARE @SQLCommand NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
        N'SELECT @OUTINT=COUNT(SYMBOL) FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName);


   EXECUTE [dbo].[sp_executesql] 
             @sqlCommand, N'@OUTINT INT OUTPUT', @OUTINT=@OUTINT OUTPUT;
END
```